# How to add custom meta to 'pre_get_terms'?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, query, terms

I have a custom taxonomy with custom meta. I have added the custom meta values to columns in the admin list page just fine. But if I search for values that are in these columns nothing is found. I'm assuming I need to use `pre_get_terms`, but am having trouble figuring out how to include the meta in the query.

[image]

Here is what I am trying to do to test one of the fields, but results are still negative.

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_terms', [$this, 'filter_feedback_stats_admin_columns'] );
public function filter_feedback_stats_admin_columns( $query ) {
    // Get the page
    global $pagenow;
    
    // Only if current post taxonomy or edit page in admin
    $taxonomy = isset($_GET['taxonomy']) ? $_GET['taxonomy'] : '';
    if ( !is_admin() || $pagenow !== 'edit-tags.php' || $taxonomy != 'feedback-stats' && !isset($_GET['s'])) {
        return $query; 
    }

    // Search keyword
    $s = $_GET['s'];
    
    // // store current query vars
    $query_vars = $query->query_vars;
    $args = [];
    
    // set meta query
    $args['meta_query'] = [
        [
        'key'       => 'access_id',
        'value'     => $s,
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ]
    ];
    
    // Add it
    $query->query_vars = array_merge( $query_vars, $args );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because the query is also searching for a match against the term name/slug, as opposed to "match either term name **or** meta field".

If you don't need the search to also look for matches by term name/slug, just unset the search term early on when you apply your meta query:

```
add_action( 'parse_term_query', function ( $wp_term_query ) {
    $taxonomy = $wp_term_query->query_vars['taxonomy'];

    $search = $wp_term_query->query_vars['search'] ?? '';

    if ( ! $search || $taxonomy !== [ 'feedback-stats' ] ) {
        return;
    }

    unset( $wp_term_query->query_vars['search'] );

    $meta_query = [
        'relation' => 'OR',
    ];

    $search_meta_keys = [
        'access_id',
        // Add your other meta keys
    ];

    foreach ( $search_meta_keys as $key ) {
        $meta_query[] = [
            'key' => $key,
            'value' => $search,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ];
    }

    $wp_term_query->query_vars['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
});
```

If you do indeed need the search to match either the term name **or** field(s), there's a bit more work ahead of you as we'll need to hook into the generated SQL of the meta query and create an `OR` search.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed @TheDeadMedic, and it works perfectly! I don't need to search name or slug. Thanks for the help!